# How do I run an external python script that's importing 3rd party library himself, in C#?

Tags: c#, python, visual-studio, speech-recognition, ironpython

I was trying to combine a Python code with C#, to use all those cool libraries like Speech Recognition inside my C# application.

I made two different projects one for python (IronPython) where I've included the module I need ([Speech Recognition](https://pypi.org/project/SpeechRecognition/)) through the python environment in VS2017 and the other one is just a console application where I want to call this app.

I thought the point was to change the searchPaths of Ironpython and afterwards it'll work.

Maybe I'm doing something wrong or maybe it just shouldn't work anyway?

---

C# Code Main.cs:

```
using IronPython.Hosting;
using System.Collections.Generic;
private static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        //Using Iron python
        var engine = IronPython.Hosting.Python.CreateEngine();
        System.Console.WriteLine("Search paths:");
        ICollection<string> searchPaths = engine.GetSearchPaths();
        foreach (string path in searchPaths)
        {
            System.Console.WriteLine(path);
        }
        System.Console.WriteLine();           
        searchPaths.Add("..\\..");
        ///Trying to add a searchPath for the place with the module I need
        searchPaths.Add(@"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual
        Studio\Shared\Anaconda3_64\Lib\site-packages");
        engine.SetSearchPaths(searchPaths);
        var res = engine.CreateScriptSourceFromFile(
        @"D:\Python\Projects\TestSpeechRecognition
        \TestForNETinPython\TestForNETinPython.py"
        );
        engine.ImportModule("speech_recognition");
        var result = res.Execute();
   }
```

Python code

```
 import speech_recognition as sr
 r = sr.Recognizer()
 with sr.Microphone() as source: 
    print ("Hello: ")
    audio = r.listen(source)
 try:
   print ("I said: " + r.recognize_google(audio))
except sr.UnknownValueError:
   print ("Cant't rec")
except sr.RequestError as e:
   print ("Can't connect: (0)".format(e))
```

---

Exception:

> Unhandled Exception: 
>   IronPython.Runtime.Exceptions.ImportException: no module named speech_recognition
>      at IronPython.Hosting.PythonService.ImportModule(ScriptEngine engine, String name)
>      at IronPython.Hosting.Python.ImportModule(ScriptEngine engine, String moduleName)
>      at Test.Program.Main(String[] args) in D:\Python\Projects\TestSpeechRecognition\Test\Program.cs:line 26

I even read some literature about creating the modules like this one http://www.needfulsoftware.com/IronPython/IronPythonCS2 or this one it's for pythonnet and a little bit creepy, but I guess it may be useful ([NoteBook](https://notebooks.azure.com/api/user/denfromufa/library/pythonnet/html/Python.NET.ipynb#%22wordpad.py%22-and-%22splitter.py%22)).
   Hope someone can use it to solve the problem.